# Mongodb c# Conditions in query LINQ

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

My query look like this:

```
var query = from p in collection
where p.MinStockQuantity >= p.StockQuantity
select p;
```

I can't run because I have exception:  Unsupported filter: `([MinStockQuantity] >= [StockQuantity])`

This query also does not work, the same bug.

```
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Product>("Product");
    var builder = Builders<Product>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.Where(o => o.MinStockQuantity > o.StockQuantity);
    var query = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

How can I compare 2 fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my previous answer was obviously wrong. You shoud use that query

```
db.products.find({ $where: "this.MinStockQuantity > this.StockQuantity" })
```

To run this query in c# world you need to use BSON documents:

```
var doc = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer
         .Deserialize<BsonDocument>
         ("{$where: \"this.MinStockQuantity > this.StockQuantity\"}");
var result = collection.Find(new CommandDocument(doc));
```

I used that query in my test application and it yells proper results.

Comment: Thanks, but I have the same bug. MongoDB does not allow for comparison between two columns from each other?

Comment: @user5472920 what are the types of columns? Mongo allows you to compare columns from same object

Comment: @user5472920 could you post here whole exception with stacktrace? Maybe there is something in inner exception

Comment: I have bad news, MongoDB don;t support this queries :(
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/bWmQ02jGi5A

These queries are not supported because LINQ and FilterDefinitionBuilder queries need to be translated into the underlying MongoDB query language, and MongoDB queries don't support comparing two fields in a document to each other.

Comment: @user5472920 I have even worse news, it works just fine :) Check my edited answer

Comment: @user5472920 no problem :) glad can help

Comment: @user5472920 you can ask another question on SO or post a comment here

Comment: @user5472920 you should use aggregation framework https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/ and there you can use $where and $sum

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824461/mongodb-c-sharp-sort-by-subcollection-field

Answer (score 1):

I know I am quite late but this works perfectly,try this :

```
  var collection = database.GetCollection<Product>("Product");
        var builder = Builders<Product>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Gt(o => o.MinStockQuantity , o.StockQuantity);
        var query = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

Gt here is greater than. 
there are various other methods like Gte =greater than equal to etc .