# Mongodb c# Sort by subcollection field

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I sort collection by field from sublist ?
My sample object looks like this:
Product:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56388c95d27d5307f4b3deef"), 
    "Name" : "Build your own computer", 
    "ProductCategories" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56388c96d27d5307f4b3df01"), 
            "CategoryId" : NumberInt(2), 
            "IsFeaturedProduct" : false, 
            "DisplayOrder" : NumberInt(1), 
            "Published" : false
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56388c96d27d5307f4b3df01"), 
            "CategoryId" : NumberInt(3), 
            "IsFeaturedProduct" : false, 
            "DisplayOrder" : NumberInt(1), 
            "Published" : false
        }
    ], 
}
```

I need to sort a list of objects products by field DisplayOrder, but for categoryId = 3 
Is this possible ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: here is a similar question about sorting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123529/how-to-specify-an-order-or-sort-using-the-c-sharp-driver-for-mongodb you need to filter, then sort

Comment: My sample code looks like this:
            var builder = Builders<Product>.Filter;
            var filter = FilterDefinition<Product>.Empty;
            filter = filter & builder.Where(x => x.ProductCategories.Any(y => y.CategoryId == 3));
            var builderSort = Builders<Product>.Sort.Ascending("ProductCategories.DisplayOrder");

            var product = collection.Find(filter).Sort(builderSort).ToListAsync().Result;

I will not sort properly.

Comment: what is the issue? Is it not sorting results? Or results are in wrong order?

Comment: results are in wrong order